# Переключение контекста на потоки в состоянии ожидания

Tags: многопоточность, unix

Вопрос чисто теоретический.

У потока может быть 3 состояния: Ожидание, Готовность и Выполнение.
Если 5 потоков в состоянии готовности будут поочередно сменять друг друга, то на переключение контекста (ПК) будет уходить много времени. Отсюда потеря производительности.

Но что, если создать еще 3 потока, которые всегда(!) будут находиться в состоянии ожидания. Планировщик ведь никогда не будет переключать контекст на них, и потери производительности мы не наблюдаем, разве что в самом начале overhead при создании потока.

Ведь так?

Comment: Я поппытался вникнуть в вопрос, и мне кажется, Вы хотите спросить следующее: "в моём ноутбуке (или ПК, или сервере) 8 ядер. Если я искусственно создам ровно столько же потоков - то каждый поток будет бежать на своём ядре, не будет переключения контекстов между ядрами, и из за этого накладые расходы на переключение потоков исчезнут" - так? Все правильно, поэтому высоконагруженные приложения пытаются выполняться в стольки потоках, сколько ядер они нашли (nginx, например). Но это не значит, что если потоков меньше, чем ядер, то они "прыгают" по ядрам и тратят время на переключение контекста.

Comment: Точнее, они действительно "прыгают", но делают это сравнительно редко, и исходя из естественныхх причин: ну, пришел там сетевой пакет, ядро занято обработкой, а потоку надо срочно продолжит исполнение - его перекинут на другое ядро. А если надо супер- оптимально, то можно поток "прибить гвоздями" к ядру. И самое главное - в современной ос потоков, бегущих одновременно, намного больше, чем ядер в типичном ПК. Другое дело - сильно нагруженные потоки, их действительно стараются сделать "столько же, сколько ядер"